# Why is this working for one semaphore but not for the other?

Tags: java, mutex, semaphore

I've been trying to make this work, but it keeps getting stuck. The part with *withdraw* works perfectly but for *create* it freezes.
`tellerReady`, `queueNotempty`, `createcomplete`, `withdrawcomplete` and others like that are semaphores. There are several classes which work fine, but the parts you see below are causing problem:

```java
//withdrawal being made
if (task == 2) {
    mutex.acquire();
    bankTellQueue.add(num);
    queueNotEmpty.release();
    mutex.release();
    tellerReady[num].acquire();
    withdraw[num] = 100 * (1 + (int) (Math.random() * 5));
    System.out.println("Customer " + num + " requests from the teller " + servingTeller[num] + " to make a withdrawal of $" + withdraw[num]);
    Thread.sleep(100);
    banktellerRequest[servingTeller[num]].release();
    withdrawalReceipt[servingTeller[num]].acquire();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("Customer " + num + " gets their cash and receipt from the teller " + servingTeller[num]);
    withdrawalComplete[servingTeller[num]].release();
}
if (task == 3) {
    mutex1.acquire();
    bankTellQueue.add(num);
    queue1NotEmpty.release();
    mutex1.release();
    tellerReady[num].acquire();
    Create[num] = num;
    System.out.println("Customer " +num + " Creates account");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    banktellerRequest[servingTeller[num]].release();
    createComplete[servingTeller[num]].acquire();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("Account created by teller " +servingTeller[num]);
    createComplete[servingTeller[num]].release();
}
```

Also there is this part in the class of `Teller`:

```java
        if (nextcustomertask == 2) {
            Customer.banktellerRequest[num].acquire();
            System.out.println("Teller " + num + " processes withdrawal for Customer " + nextcustomer);
            Thread.sleep(300);
            Customer.customerBalance[nextcustomer] = Customer.customerBalance[nextcustomer] - Customer.withdraw[nextcustomer];
            Customer.withdrawalReceipt[num].release();
            Customer.withdrawalComplete[num].acquire();
        }

        //handling create account
        if(nextcustomertask ==3 ) {
            Customer.banktellerRequest[num].acquire();
            System.out.println("Teller " + num + " processes Create account for customer " + nextcustomer);
            Thread.sleep(300);

            Customer.customerBalance[nextcustomer] = 1000;
            Customer.createReceipt[num].release();
            Customer.createComplete[num].acquire();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I found where the problem was. I was using the wrong semaphore.

Comment: you might want to consider a `switch` statement instead of `if`s. And refactoring to methods.

Comment: @roddyofthefrozenpeas The professor specifically asked not to use switch otherwise I would've used it. The problem us somewhere else. The customer doesn't release the teller when it's time to use the create function.